# Is is possible to decrypt MD5 passwords?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if its possible to decrypt MD5 passwords

Comment: What do you mean by _view them like a real password_??

Comment: http://php.net/faq.passwords.php - For real it looks like you have no clue. - Please double safety then for anything related to security.

Comment: I guess, you want to know how to decrypt "md5 encrypted password" to bring it back to normal. Right? MD5 is one-way algorithm. It cant be decrypted. But, you can use some online MD5 dictionary to get original password like [this](http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/) or [this](http://www.md5online.org/)

Comment: There is no way to get your real password again after encrypted by md5()

Comment: @this – Bhavik Shah  you pretily understood well thats the thng

Comment: @oktopus to decript them to normal

Comment: Decryption isn't possible. Nor should you do such thing in a public available application. Have a look at the answer from Quentin. Thats the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I generate passwords to the users automatically using md5

Don't. [MD5 isn't safe](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash).

> how to I encrypt these passwords and I view them like a real password

I think you mean "decrypt". You can't. MD5 is a hashing algorithm, it is designed to be non-reversible.

Don't generate passwords for your users. Your process should be:

1. User generates password
2. User sends password to you over SSL
3. You hash the password (not with MD5)
4. You store the hashed password

When the user logs in:

1. User sends password to you over SSL
2. You hash the password
3. You compare the hashed password with the hash in your database

Comment: Actually you can decrypt it with bruteforce, if it's not too long.

Comment: @Dropout — No, you can't. With brute force you can find *an* input that will, when MD5ed, give the same output as the password, but there is no way to know if that is the original password.

Comment: @Quentin great  job appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just store them in the database encrypted - that's what it's for.

Generate a password:

```
$characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$your_password_length = 8;
$password_unencrypted = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $your_password_length; $i++) {
  $password_unencrypted .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
```

Now encrypt it

```
$password_encrypted = md5($password_unencrypted);
```

Now you have two variables - password_unencrypted and password_encrypted. You can send the password_unencrypted to the user via mail for example, but DB should contain an encrypted password. When user logs in you should compare his encrypted input with the encrypted password in the DB:

```
//..get the md5 from DB to $password_encrypted and then
if (md5($_POST['users_password_in_form']) == $password_encrypted){
// ...log in...
}
```

Comment: MD5 shouldn't be used for that anymore! Use SHA-1 or similar instead. Also thats not encryption but one way hashing!

Comment: @oktopus — SHA-1 isn't safe either.

Comment: @Quentin: The question is: What is safe? If the password has a length of only 6 to 8 characters and no salt or recursive hashing is used, every hash could be calculated using the cloud in a short enough amount of time. But what hash-method would you prefer instead?

Answer (score 1):

About password and database secure, minding that the only way to user have acess to the password`s is if he somehow acess the database itself (probably he got the password), so does it really make`s diference if the password is hashed or encrypted?
  I`m asking cause we are trying to protect the user password, but if someone has acess to the database, he dont need the user password, he can make the changes on the database itself, and about the encrypting, i find on php manual that blowfish is the most indicated, but i`ve found a online decrypter in the first result search in google.
  What you think about that? Thank you in advance.